# Android project fail to run on Azure pipeline but works fine locally

Tags: android, azure-pipelines

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> Your current JDK is located in  /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.332-9/x64/Contents/Home/jre
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error message, your project has been set to require Java 11. However, the default Java version installed on the agent machine is Java 8.

In Azure Pipelines, when the default Java version installed on the agent machine is not consistent with that required by your project, you can use the [**Java Tool Installer task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) to install the required Java version. This task will install the specified Java version and set it to the **`JAVA_HOME`** environment variable on the agent machine.

Then in the subsequent tasks in the same job, the specified Java version will be used by default.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekSrivastava, I have not heard from you for a long time. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my answer? Have you tried as the suggestions mentioned in my answer? Are the suggestions helpful for you?
As suggested, you can use the Java Tool Installer task  in the pipeline job to install the required Java version.

Answer (score 4):

Yea, I was having the same issue on Azure Pipelines with mac-latest.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     Your current JDK is located in  /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.352-8/x64/Contents/Home/jre
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I used JavaToolInstaller to set JAVA_HOME to 11 and then had to update gradle.properties and set org.gradle.java.home to the value in JAVA_HOME. Hope this helps someone else.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.17.1'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

- script: |
    npm install
    cd android
    echo "org.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_HOME" >> ./gradle.properties
  displayName: 'Android Setup Script'

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 'android/'
    gradleWrapperFile: 'android/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    tasks: 'assembleRelease'
    options: '-PversionName=$(Build.BuildNumber) -PversionCode=$(Build.BuildId)'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'upload.keystore'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(AndroidKeyStorePassword)'
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(AndroidKeyAlias)'
    apksignerKeyPassword: '$(AndroidKeyPassword)'
    zipalign: false
```

Comment: I'll add a little fix:

`echo "\norg.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_HOME" >> ./gradle.properties`

Because if you don't have a free line in you gradle.properties it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
trigger:
- CDCI
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.17.1'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

# - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
#   inputs:
#       versionSpec: "8"
#       jdkArchitectureOption: x64
#       jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: "11"
      jdkArchitectureOption: x64
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
- script: |
    npm install
    cd android
    echo "org.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_HOME" >> ./gradle.properties
  displayName: 'Android Setup Script'

# - script: |
#     java -version
#   env:
#     JAVA_HOME: $(JAVA_HOME_8_X64)
#     PATH: $(JAVA_HOME_8_X64)/bin;$(PATH)

# - script: |
#     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME]$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)"
#     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)\bin;$(PATH)"
#   displayName: "Set java version"

# Gradle v1
# Build using a Gradle wrapper script.

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    tasks: 'assembleRelease'
    options: '-PversionName=$(Build.BuildNumber) -PversionCode=$(Build.BuildId)'
    # Download secure file
    # Download a secure file to the agent machine
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'keystore.jks'
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
        apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
        apksignerKeystoreFile: 'keystore.jks'
        apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(jarsignerKeystorePassword)'
        apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(keyAlias)'
        apksignerKeyPassword: '$(jarsignerKeyPassword)'
        zipalign: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.apk'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'appcenter login --token c47e589dadcc75a75fc51e211d7144f245da9e8c'
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'AppCentreServiceConnection'
    appSlug: 'tauqeer.majeed-auxilium.digital/AirPortr'
    appFile: 'app/release/app-release.apk'
    buildVersion: '1.1'
    releaseNotesOption: 'file'
    releaseNotesFile: 'release-notes.txt'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: '667d2623-9734-4b84-84ce-8deb0e919928'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).